# Why can't Loopback Address be used as source address inside packet?

Tags: networking, ip

We know that we can ping Localhost which means it can be used as Destination Address.

Why can't Loopback Address be used as Source Address inside packet?

Comment: Any address in the `127.0.0.0/8` block can never appear anywhere on any network, nor can any address in that block be used as a source or destination address for packets outside the host. RFC 3330, Special-Use IPv4 Addresses: "_127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host loopback address. A datagram sent by a higher level protocol to an address anywhere within this block should loop back inside the host. This is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback, but no addresses within this block should ever appear on any network anywhere [RFC1700, page 5]._"

Answer (score 2):

It can be used as the source address, and in fact it is the source address when you pinged localhost!

Network traffic to/from localhost is the same as any other network traffic except that it never leaves the host. The localhost address is both source and destination address.